# How to persist nested Bundle in Android?

Tags: android

I have a Bundle with a nested nature that I want to preserve, how can I persist the whole Bundle most easily? `SharedPreferences` lacks a bundle feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a `Bundle`. A `Bundle` is not meant to be persisted. Use a different data model (POJOs, `HashMap`, whatever) and write persistence logic (serialize, serialize to JSON, serialize to XML, write to SQLite, etc.).